# Symfony Request POST

Tags: url-routing, symfony

Currently I am working on symfony project, however some errors are thrown when I try to perform that. As an example:

> Controller `MyAppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::updateAction()`
>   requires that you provide a value for the "`$request`" argument (because
>   there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one).

My Routing:

```
anasayfa:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller:MyAppBundle:Default:index}
listele:
    path: /listele
    defaults: {_controller:MyAppBundle:Default:listele}
update:
    path: /update
    defaults: {_controller:MyAppBundle:Default:update}
    requirements:
    methods: POST
```

And my Controllers:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $username = $request->request->get('username');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');
}
```

Finally my form in homepage(index):

```
<form action="{{ path('update') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Give Username">
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Give Password">
    <input type="submit" value="kaydet">
</form>
```

I am using symfony version 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller file. You used:

```
updateAction(Request $request)
```

But you are using the correct `Request` object? It should be

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
```